# Electron: Open With Context Menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In Electron, I would like to use a context menu to utilize the "Open With" submenu as is done on Mac OS. Is this functionality possible in electron?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding this to your `electron-builder-config.json`:

```
   "fileAssociations": [
        {
            "ext": ["txt", "md", "yml"],
            "name": "Plain Text",
            "role": "Editor"
        }
    ],
```

From https://github.com/rchrd2/example-electron-file-association

See also:
https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#PlatformSpecificBuildOptions-fileAssociations